# Nested System.import in Javascript

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I am struggling with Javascript and System.import

I have the following and further Methods inside

```
System.import("frm/core").then(function(core) {
    core.companionScript("something", function ($element, options) {
    "use strict";
```

Now I need to integrate another **import System.import("frm/mod/messages")** containing a method addMessages

I tried the following

```
System.import("frm/core").then(function(core) {
    System.import("frm/mod/messages").then(function() {

    core.companionScript("something", function ($element, options) {
    "use strict";
```

further down in the existing code I try to invoke the addMessage but It does not work at all.
It always fails with an error that the method ist not present.

This is what I try to do in side an existing function

```
                 function doSomething(password){
                 ……
                     if(condition) {
                         addMEssages("p1", "p2", {errors : ["errKEy"]});
                               }
                  ……
                 }
```

Comment: Are you sure it is addMessages and not addMEssages?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo in my example